# how to keep scrollview contentoffset in cell after reload cell swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.item]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellClass
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didLike(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
}



@objc func didLike(sender: UIButton) {
    let post = self.posts[sender.tag]
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0)
    self.posts[sender.tag] = self.selectLikeButton(post: post)

    self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

}
```

CellClass

```
class NoticeLetterViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: CustomImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var userNameButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var optionButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var letterTextView: MyLetterStyleTextView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemButtons: UIStackView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var commentButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sendMessage: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bookmark: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var likeCounter: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var captionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeAgo: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var startVoiceButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var commentViewButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var commentCountLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastComment: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var goCommentView: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var pageStack: UIStackView!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollImageView: UIScrollView! {
    didSet {
        self.scrollImageView.delegate = self

    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var pageLeftView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: FlexiblePageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var pageRightView: UIView!

 }


extension NoticeLetterViewCell: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let page = Int(floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
    self.pageControl.setCurrentPage(at: page)

}
```

In a collection view controller, in a cell
After using self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath]), the position of the scroll view in the cell changes. I'd like to save the original location and use it, but it's too difficult. T.T

Comment: Do you want the scrollview to return to the position when it first was loaded or where it was scrolled to?

Comment: If the scroll was 3 pages, I would like to have 3 pages after reloading

Comment: why don't you create an array of how far is scrolled for each item.Then when you reload, push the array[indexPath.row] to the Custom View and scroll to that number?

Comment: Do I need to get the value via scrollViewDidScroll in the CellClass?
How can I pass a value in a CellClass to collectionview class?

Comment: What I'm thinking is you pass the ViewController as an optional into the cell in the cell for row at indexpath and continue to update the data there. If you want I can add what I'm thinking as an answer and delete it if it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what to do. Can you help me? I want your advice .. T.T

Comment: OK. I'll write it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if this will work as its very long and overly complex but I can't think of anything else.

ViewController

```
 var scrollArray = [Int]()
 var runbefore = false

 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.item]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellClass
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didLike(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) 

     cell.viewpassed = self
     cell.indexofCell = indexPath.row

     if scrollArray[indexPath.row] != nil {
         cell.movetoNumber = scrollArray[indexPath.row]
     }

     if runbefore == false {
         scrollArray.append(0)
         if indexPath.row = posts.count - 1 {
            runbefore = true
         }
     }
}
```

Cell Class

```
    extension NoticeLetterViewCell: UIScrollViewDelegate {

       var movetoNumber = 0
       var indexofCell = 0
       public weak var viewpassed : ViewController? //This is what class you have the cell for item at function

       override func awakeFromNib() {
            if movetoNumber != 0 {
             //Move the scrollView to movetoNumberPoint Run whatever action your Want HERE
            }
       }

       func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
           let page = Int(floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
           if page != 0 {
                viewpassed.scrollArray.remove(at: indexofCell)
                viewpassed.scrollArray.insert(page, at: indexofCell)
           }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I guess my explanation was not enough.
Like an Instagram, the contentoffset of the scroll view should not change. When I touch the like button to refresh the cell.
----
I try to apply the above code but it does not work
T.T... I am sorry that my English level is low.

Comment: Did you add your code to the commented area to move the scrollview? That must be entered

Comment: The page was calculated by scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. And passed the value and applied when reloading.

Comment: func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        self.pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
        self.moveToNumber = Int(page)
        viewpassed?.posts[indexofCell].page = self.moveToNumber
    }

Comment: Did it work? That’s great! Edit my answer with that code